# How to use 'setReadyOnly' for a particular session of ACE editor

Tags: javascript, web, ace-editor

I have multiple ace editors in my page. I have done so by replacing all the  on the page to ace editor using the code below :

https://gist.github.com/duncansmart/5267653

I would like to set some of them editable and some of them readonly using 'setReadOnly' property of editor.

But when I use 'editor.setReadOnly(flag)' inside for loop, it changes the ReadOnly property of all ace editors.

If I do editor.getSession().setReadOnly(flag), I get an error

**TypeError: undefined is not a function**

In the above code, flag is either true or false.
Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the problem.

It value "true" passed as argument inside setReadOnly was fetched from textarea using 'get' function from domAttr(Dojo).

So the type of variable was a string.

I typecasted it to boolean using following code :

```
var editStringFlag=domAttr.get(textarea,'editFlag');
var editBoolFlag = (editStringFlag==='true')
editor.setReadOnly(editBoolFlag);
```

This resolved the issue